# Disk shows wrong size on DF, correct size in gparted and vmware

Tags: hard-disk, fsck, gparted

I created a new backup system and initially tested everything with a 2.5TB disk. Once the idea worked out, I went to increase the disk to 7.5TB. I increase my volume on the SAN, then increased the disk in VMWare to 7.5TB. Then, went in to `gParted` and increased to 7.5TB but now im still seeing only 2.5TB total size on the disk when I do `df -h`

Here are the outputs of some needed information:

Paste from `df -h`

```
/dev/sdc                 2.5T   17G  2.3T   1% /usr/local/bananas/
```

Here is `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 8246.3 GB, 8246337208320 bytes, 16106127360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an 
experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.
```

From `e2fsck -f /dev/sdc`

```
[root@computer ~]# e2fsck -f /dev/sdc 
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sdc: 341359/163840000 files (2.6% non-contiguous), 
14564432/655360000 blocks
```

Im running this on a Centos6 system. It looks like the disk is actually storing data properly but it won't go past 2.5TB even though everything else is showing it is set larger. Any ideas on this issue would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wiped out the partitions and then created a new partition, and then reformatted it as XFS. Everything is showing up properly in all forms of disk checking.